# Why ambient temperature used to measure pressure for car ac system

Tags: hvac, theory

Since the ac system is located mostly inside a car engine and the car is warmed up prior to adding freon, and the temp/humidity in engine bay is different  from ambient temperature//humidity, and all of the above is done with car in parked position, why is ambient temperature used to measure pressure instead of temps closer to engine area with hood open.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Because part of the a/c system is also in the car cabin and not under the hood.

Comment: Okay. But then why is the car cabin the least common denominator and not the car engine when measuring pressure.

Comment: Think about the a/c circuit - the compressor causes the pressure rise and the throttle or expansion valve reduces it.... where are those components and which components are downstream of them....

Comment: Try plotting the cycle on an H-S diagram and evaluating the presdures around the circuit based on the temperatures...

Comment: I think i understand better why pressure is measured based on ambient temp. We want cold air inside the car which would be at ambient temp and so our measurements are all relative to cabin air.  Also since placement of evaporator is in cabin area we are concerned about what temp/pressure values are needed in evaporator for optimal cooling of cabin air.

Comment: I am still trying to understand the science behind it and so the H-S diagram is new to me. But thanks for the pointer. I am reading more on it.